# vb.NET: Dictionary, TryGetValue and Infinite

Tags: vb.net

I have a question regarding the TryGetValue method of Dictionary class. I have implemented a class which inherits of Dictionary(Of T,V) and has a lookup method. In this method I have to get a match or mismatch comparing with some values. I use the TryGetValue method but if one of the value is an Infinite (it could be because of my data) then the TryGetValue throwns the following error: "System.OverflowException: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow." Sorry, but I don't get the reason, can anybody give me a hand?
Thanks,

Edited: piece of code: here obs = [2, -Inf]. When i = 1 then I get the excepction.

Dim found as Boolean = Me.TryGetValue(obs(i), value)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Post code. Probably a bug but without seeing code it's impossible to give any help.

Comment: I created a dictionary of doubles, added infinity to it and TryGetValue worked. We need more information.

Comment: Thanks @-the_lotus, I think the key is: dictionary of objects.

Comment: What are the actual types used in the Dictionary?

Comment: The type is Dictionary(Of Object, Object). Thanks